# How do I execute a custom code function only once on a web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis

I want to execute some code only once on start of a web service.
I thought to use  `void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)`   but I have in my code

```
`Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"];`
```

and I get exception   `Request is not available in this context` seems  object probably doesn't exist yet becase the application is just starting and not processing Requests.

Any idea how I can solve this issue ? 
How I can execute my code only once .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a static Boolean field initialized to `false` to mark whether the function was called and set it to `true` one it was called (best done at the end of the function).

Only execute the code in the function if the value is `false`.

Do this with appropriate locking to avoid the possible race condition (thanks Yahia).

Comment: isn't that prone to a race condition without any locking ?

Comment: @Yahia - Fair point. Added info regarding appropriate locking.